# Getting max vaule using reduce()

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

```
maxScore = functools.reduce(lambda x, y: max(x['score'], y['score']), data)
print(maxScore)

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-110-01bfe99b000b> in <module>()
----> 1 maxScore = functools.reduce(lambda x, y: max(x['score'], y['score']), data)
      2 print(maxScore)

<ipython-input-110-01bfe99b000b> in <lambda>(x, y)
----> 1 maxScore = functools.reduce(lambda x, y: max(x['score'], y['score']), data)
      2 print(maxScore)

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

The data are:

```
{'action': 'Violations were cited in the following area(s).',
  'bbl': '4113240001',
  'bin': '4244445',
  'boro': 'Queens',
  'building': '22315',
  'camis': '41699792',
  'census_tract': '059600',
  'community_board': '413',
  'council_district': '27',
  'critical_flag': 'Y',
  'cuisine_description': 'Caribbean',
  'dba': "MERITTA'S JAMAICAN AND AMERICAN RESTAURANT",
  'grade': 'A',
  'grade_date': '2019-04-29T00:00:00.000',
  'inspection_date': '2019-04-29T00:00:00.000',
  'inspection_type': 'Cycle Inspection / Re-inspection',
  'latitude': '40.694248351255',
  'longitude': '-73.737295424635',
  'nta': 'QN33',
  'phone': '7185270136',
  'record_date': '2019-08-04T06:01:16.000',
  'score': '10',
  'street': 'LINDEN BOULEVARD',
  'violation_code': '04L',
  'violation_description': "Evidence of mice or live mice present in facility's food and/or non-food areas.",
  'zipcode': '11411'},
 {'action': 'Violations were cited in the following area(s).',
  'bbl': '4007000047',
  'bin': '4012143',
  'boro': 'Queens',
  'building': '44-01',
  'camis': '50001785',
  'census_tract': '014700',
  'community_board': '401',
  'council_district': '22',
  'critical_flag': 'N',
  'cuisine_description': 'Delicatessen',
  'dba': 'LA LUNA CAFE',
  'grade': 'A',
  'grade_date': '2018-12-03T00:00:00.000',
  'inspection_date': '2018-12-03T00:00:00.000',
  'inspection_type': 'Cycle Inspection / Re-inspection',
  'latitude': '40.762333015514',
  'longitude': '-73.911670635234',
  'nta': 'QN70',
  'phone': '7186060094',
  'record_date': '2019-08-04T06:01:16.000',
  'score': '13',
  'street': '30TH AVE',
  'violation_code': '08C',
  'violation_description': 'Pesticide use not in accordance with label or applicable laws. Prohibited chemical used/stored. Open bait station used.',
  'zipcode': '11103'},
 {'action': 'Violations were cited in the following area(s).',
  'bbl': '5036170001',
  'bin': '5052234',
  'boro': 'Staten Island',
  'building': '2333',
  'camis': '50048016',
  'census_tract': '012200',
  'community_board': '502',
  'council_district': '50',
  'critical_flag': 'Y',
  'cuisine_description': 'Asian',
  'dba': 'SIMPLE ASIA',
  'grade': 'A',
  'grade_date': '2016-11-01T00:00:00.000',
  'inspection_date': '2016-11-01T00:00:00.000',
  'inspection_type': 'Pre-permit (Operational) / Re-inspection',
  'latitude': '40.573990387537',
  'longitude': '-74.106221480135',
  'nta': 'SI45',
  'phone': '9178252981',
  'record_date': '2019-08-04T06:01:16.000',
  'score': '10',
  'street': 'HYLAN BLVD',
  'violation_code': '06F',
  'violation_description': 'Wiping cloths soiled or not stored in sanitizing solution.',
  'zipcode': '10306'},
 {'action': 'Establishment Closed by DOHMH.  Violations were cited in the following area(s) and those requiring immediate action were addressed.',
  'bbl': '2057060001',
  'bin': '2083167',
  'boro': 'Bronx',
  'building': '249',
  'camis': '41690532',
  'census_tract': '028900',
  'community_board': '208',
  'council_district': '11',
  'critical_flag': 'Y',
  'cuisine_description': 'American',
  'dba': 'KINGSBRIDGE DONUT SHOP',
  'inspection_date': '2019-07-25T00:00:00.000',
  'inspection_type': 'Cycle Inspection / Re-inspection',
  'latitude': '40.879751741296',
  'longitude': '-73.906454907184',
  'nta': 'BX29',
  'phone': '3473464171',
  'record_date': '2019-08-04T06:01:16.000',
  'score': '68',
  'street': 'WEST  231 STREET',
  'violation_code': '05F',
  'violation_description': 'Insufficient or no refrigerated or hot holding equipment to keep potentially hazardous foods at required temperatures.',
  'zipcode': '10463'}
```

Comment: What is `data`? Show a [mcve]. It appears to be a list of Strings, not dictionaries. Also, this doesn't look like it will work as you're expecting. `max` will return a number, which will make the accumulator of the reduction a number, and `x['score']` doesn't make sense if `x` is a number. You shouldn't try to index the accumulator.

Comment: The data is from this link: https://data.cityofnewyork.us/Health/DOHMH-New-York-City-Restaurant-Inspection-Results/43nn-pn8j

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to sum the values (reduce) or find the maximum?

Imagine, this is your JSON (I've prettified it and made an array):

```
[
  {
    "action": "Violations were cited in the following area(s).",
    "bbl": "4113240001",
    "bin": "4244445",
    "boro": "Queens",
    "building": "22315",
    "camis": "41699792",
    "census_tract": "059600",
    "community_board": "413",
    "council_district": "27",
    "critical_flag": "Y",
    "cuisine_description": "Caribbean",
    "dba": "MERITTA'S JAMAICAN AND AMERICAN RESTAURANT",
    "grade": "A",
    "grade_date": "2019-04-29T00:00:00.000",
    "inspection_date": "2019-04-29T00:00:00.000",
    "inspection_type": "Cycle Inspection / Re-inspection",
    "latitude": "40.694248351255",
    "longitude": "-73.737295424635",
    "nta": "QN33",
    "phone": "7185270136",
    "record_date": "2019-08-04T06:01:16.000",
    "score": "10",
    "street": "LINDEN BOULEVARD",
    "violation_code": "04L",
    "violation_description": "Evidence of mice or live mice present in facility's food and/or non-food areas.",
    "zipcode": "11411"
  },
  {
    "action": "Violations were cited in the following area(s).",
    "bbl": "4007000047",
    "bin": "4012143",
    "boro": "Queens",
    "building": "44-01",
    "camis": "50001785",
    "census_tract": "014700",
    "community_board": "401",
    "council_district": "22",
    "critical_flag": "N",
    "cuisine_description": "Delicatessen",
    "dba": "LA LUNA CAFE",
    "grade": "A",
    "grade_date": "2018-12-03T00:00:00.000",
    "inspection_date": "2018-12-03T00:00:00.000",
    "inspection_type": "Cycle Inspection / Re-inspection",
    "latitude": "40.762333015514",
    "longitude": "-73.911670635234",
    "nta": "QN70",
    "phone": "7186060094",
    "record_date": "2019-08-04T06:01:16.000",
    "score": "13",
    "street": "30TH AVE",
    "violation_code": "08C",
    "violation_description": "Pesticide use not in accordance with label or applicable laws. Prohibited chemical used/stored. Open bait station used.",
    "zipcode": "11103"
  },
  {
    "action": "Violations were cited in the following area(s).",
    "bbl": "5036170001",
    "bin": "5052234",
    "boro": "Staten Island",
    "building": "2333",
    "camis": "50048016",
    "census_tract": "012200",
    "community_board": "502",
    "council_district": "50",
    "critical_flag": "Y",
    "cuisine_description": "Asian",
    "dba": "SIMPLE ASIA",
    "grade": "A",
    "grade_date": "2016-11-01T00:00:00.000",
    "inspection_date": "2016-11-01T00:00:00.000",
    "inspection_type": "Pre-permit (Operational) / Re-inspection",
    "latitude": "40.573990387537",
    "longitude": "-74.106221480135",
    "nta": "SI45",
    "phone": "9178252981",
    "record_date": "2019-08-04T06:01:16.000",
    "score": "10",
    "street": "HYLAN BLVD",
    "violation_code": "06F",
    "violation_description": "Wiping cloths soiled or not stored in sanitizing solution.",
    "zipcode": "10306"
  },
  {
    "action": "Establishment Closed by DOHMH. Violations were cited in the following area(s) and those requiring immediate action were addressed.",
    "bbl": "2057060001",
    "bin": "2083167",
    "boro": "Bronx",
    "building": "249",
    "camis": "41690532",
    "census_tract": "028900",
    "community_board": "208",
    "council_district": "11",
    "critical_flag": "Y",
    "cuisine_description": "American",
    "dba": "KINGSBRIDGE DONUT SHOP",
    "inspection_date": "2019-07-25T00:00:00.000",
    "inspection_type": "Cycle Inspection / Re-inspection",
    "latitude": "40.879751741296",
    "longitude": "-73.906454907184",
    "nta": "BX29",
    "phone": "3473464171",
    "record_date": "2019-08-04T06:01:16.000",
    "score": "68",
    "street": "WEST 231 STREET",
    "violation_code": "05F",
    "violation_description": "Insufficient or no refrigerated or hot holding equipment to keep potentially hazardous foods at required temperatures.",
    "zipcode": "10463"
  }
]
```

To find the maximum use:

```py
maxScore = float(max(json.loads(data), key = lambda k: float(k['score']))['score'])
# maxScore = 68.0
```

Here max will find the maximal record by score ("Establishment Closed by DOHMH…") and then you can get any of it's properties.

To sum the scores:

```py
totalScore = functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x + float(y['score']), json.loads(data), 0)
# totalScore = 101.1
```

Here you start from zero and sum up the scores.

Bot examples require to import `functools` and `json` and I've tried to stay as max close to your initial one-liner as I coudld. Depending on you intention there may be more efficient ways to calculate the result.